# How to forward port 80 to 8080 in os x mavericks

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks, ipfw

I installed Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9), and I'm using [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) to publish a web app. I type

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

(my hosts file has `127.0.0.1 abc.com`)

but Safari can't connect to abc.com. It worked in OS X 10.8 though. Why?

Comment: [According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5413) `ipfw` was depreciated as of Mountain Lion (10.8). `pf` should be used instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ipfw` has been deprecated since Mountain Lion but was not removed until Mavericks.
It's now using the ported `pf` exclusively.

I wrote a [quick guide](https://gist.github.com/kujohn/7209628) to configure and setup pf for port forwarding in Mavericks.